# Parameter Tampering in checkmarx

Tags: javascript, java, checkmarx

scan my code in checkmarx and it throws me this vulnerability, I already searched but I can't find the solution, could you help me? thank you very much here my code.

The vulnerability is marked in the line @RequestParam int region in region

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ReporteNormal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void obtenerReportes(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam int region,
        @RequestParam String fechaInicio,
        @RequestParam String fechaFin) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    reporteService.obtenerReporte(request, response, region, fechaInicio, fechaFin, startTime);
}
```

Comment: Can a caller do something bad by passing a different value for `region`? If not, this is a false positive and should be marked as such. If so, you need to do some validation of the value (such as checking that it is a valid region for the logged-in user) and then probably mark it as fixed or something.